# Why useState hook doesn't update in WebView onScroll event?

Tags: react-native, events, webview, state, use-state

I'm trying to create a workaround to calculate/get content height which should be rendered inside React Native WebView component.

For that Im artificially calling onScroll event with Javascript , then trying to update state with the actual content height. But even console log shows different values for content height, which should trigger state update , it doesnt happen. Only when really scrolling it gets updated. But its for sure that even without scrolling the event is triggered as console log is working.

Any idea why here state update fails? (In the code snippet some backticks are missing)

```
    const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(10);

    const webViewScript = 
     setTimeout(function() { 
     window.postMessage(document.body.scrollDown); 
     }, 1000);
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
      ;


    <WebView
      injectedJavaScript={window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(${webViewScript})}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      onScroll={(event) =>
      setContentHeight(Number(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height));
      }
      javaScriptEnabled
      style={{ height: contentHeight }}
      source={{ html: htmlTempl, baseUrl: '' }}
    />
```